# Template function in non-template class - Division between H and CPP files

Tags: c++, templates

I was (and have been for a long time) under the impression that you had to fully define all template functions in your .h files to avoid multiple definition errors that occur due to the template compilation process (non C++11).

I was reading a co-worker's code, and he had a non-template class that had a template function declared in it, and he separated the function declaration from the function definition (declared in H, defined in CPP).  It compiles and works fine to my surprise.

Is there a difference between how a template function in a non template class is compiled, and how a function in a template class is compiled?  Can someone explain what that difference is or where I might be confused?

Comment: Did he call that template function from outside its own CPP?

Comment: In this instance he doesn't - how does that impact the situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interesting bit is how and when the template gets instantiated. If the instantiations can be found at link time, the template *definition* doesn't need to be visible in the header file.

Sometimes, explicit instantiations are cause like this:

- header :

  ```
  struct X { 
      // function template _declaration_
      template <typename T> void test(const T&);
  };
  ```
- cpp:

  ```
  #include "X.h"

  // function template _definition_:
  template <typename T> 
      void X::test(const T&)
  {
  }

  // explicit function template _instantiation(s)_:
  template X::test<int>(const int&);    
  template X::test<std::string>(const std::string&);
  ```

Using this sample, linking will succeed unless uninstantiated definitions of the template are used in other translation units

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between function templates defined in namespace or in class scope. It also doesn't matter whether is inside class template or not. What matter is that at some point in the project any used function template (whether member or non-member) is instantiated. Let's go over the different situations:

1. Unused function templates don't need to be instantiated and thus their implementation doesn't need to be visible to compiler at any point in time. This sounds boring but is important e.g. when using SFINAE approaches where class or function templates are declared but not defined.
2. Any function template which is defined where it is used will be instantiated by the compiler in a form which allows multiple definitions across different translation units: only one of the instantiations is retained. It is important that all the different definitions are merged because you could detect differences if you took the address of a function template or used a state variable inside the function template: there shall be only one of these for each instantiation.
3. The most interesting setup is where the definition of the function template is **not** seen when the function template is used: in this case the compiler cannot instantiate it. When the compiler sees a definition of the function template in a different translation unit it wouldn't know which template arguments to instantiate! A [Catch 22](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_%28logic%29)? Well, you can always explicitly instantiate a template once. Having multiple explicit instantiations would create multiply defined symbols.

These are roughly the important options. There are often good reasons that you don't want to have the definition of a function template in the header. For example, you don't necessarily want to drag in dependencies you wouldn't have otherwise. Putting the definition of the function template somewhere else and explicitly instantiating it is a good thing. Also, you might want to reduce the compile time e.g. by avoiding to instantiate essentially the entire I/O stream and locale library in every translation unit using the stream. In C++ 2011 *extern templates* were introduced which allow the declaration that a particular template (either function or class template) is defined externally once for the entire program and there isn't any need to instantiate it in every header using particularly common template arguments.

For a longer version of what I just said, including examples have a look at a [blog post](http://kuhllcom)
I wrote last weekend on this topic.